# PHP/MySQL: Rebuild primary key field

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, reset, rebuild

### Problem:

Primary key field is `'ID'`

Data is inserted/updated into it using a `REPLACE INTO` command, which is easy to use but unfortunately increases the `'ID'` value of the Record it is replacing.

So I need a way to completely rebuild the `ID` feild so that:

```
| ID  |  Name   |
|===============
| 21  |  deer   |
| 8   |  snow   |
| 3   |  tracks |
| 14  |  arrow  |
```

Goes to:

```
| ID |  Name   |
|===============
| 1  |  deer   |
| 2  |  snow   |
| 3  |  tracks |
| 4  |  arrow  |
```

and I need to do it through php.

### Current Attempts:

```
<?php
$reset = "SET @num := 0;
UPDATE `users` SET `ID` = @num := (@num+1);
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;";

$con = mysql_connect("mysql2.000webhost.com","db_user","password");  
if (!$con)
{
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);
if (!mysql_query($reset,$con)) 
  {
    die('<h1>Nope:</h1>' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and trying:

```
$reset = "ALTER TABLE `users` DROP `ID`;
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `ID` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;`";
```

also yielded no results.

### Strangness of it all

Both the `$reset` commands I tried both execute perfectly in MySQL, but for some reason they fail to act properly from PHP.

---

### Answer

As pointed out the answer, @ variables are preserved per connection, so it is perfectly reasonable to run multiple queries:

```
///Trigger multiple queries
$nope = '<h1>Nope:</h1>  ';
$res1 = "SET @num := 0;";
$res2 = "UPDATE `users` SET `ID` = @num := (@num+1);";
$res3 = "ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;";
if (!mysql_query($res1,$con)) die($nope . mysql_error());
if (!mysql_query($res2,$con)) die($nope . mysql_error());
if (!mysql_query($res3,$con)) die($nope . mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_*` does not support running multiple queries. You have to run them separately

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense. But how do I run multiple queries whilst still preserving the `@num` variable across them?

Comment: Variables are preserver per connection, so it should be ok.

Comment: Ok, let me try it out before I tick as answer

Comment: @tetris you run them one by one using the same mysql_connect()

Comment: Yep -- works. Updating the answer into my question. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

1. if you use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, you can keep your 'ID'

Comment: True, but if I have a lot of fields, then the `UPDATE .... ` would be very long and involved right?

Comment: i offen use `$fields = array();` fill it whit the changes and then do: `$query = "INSERT INTO table SET " . implode(', ', $fields) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " . implode(', ', $fields);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function table2array ($table_name, $unique_col = 'id')
    {
$tmp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name"); $count = mysql_num_rows($tmp);
while($rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($tmp));
array_pop($rows);
for ($c=0; $c < $count; $c++) 
{
  $array[$rows[$c][$unique_col]] = $rows[$c];
}
return $array;
    }

function reindexTable($table_name,$startFrom = 1) // simply call this function where you need a table to be reindexed!
    {
$array = table2array($table_name);
$id = 1; foreach ($array as $row) 
{
mysql_query("UPDATE `".$table_name."` SET `id` = '".$id."' WHERE `".$table_name."`.`id` = ".$row['id']);
$id++;
}
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE  `".$table_name."` AUTO_INCREMENT = ".$id);
    }
```